# Render personal tabs dynamically in Ms-Teams using custom application

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I have created custom application with static tabs defined in manifest file and it is working fine.
Now, our requirement is that we need to render static (personal) tabs dynamically according to provided Site URL by customer.

**For ex.** When application installed in teams user will get screen where he will asked for Site URL (API) in textbox and submit it. This will internally check data and give response with tab name, tab URLs and other details then I need to render this tabs dynamically in teams.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PrQmJ.png)

Please provide solution for this how I can achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to add static tabs dynamically. [Static or personal tabs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/build-your-first-app/build-personal-tab) are always added through the app manifest and are common to all the users using the app. If you want to configure what tabs to show you can try using a [channel tab](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/build-your-first-app/build-channel-tab).

Comment: Using channel tab it is showing tabs which we can configure at teams/group scope. I want to render tab as personal tab dynamically. Is there any way where we can write code and configure to render it dynamically ?

Answer (score 0):

As Gousia said, you can't set the contents of the tab dynamically, and you can't add/remove personal tabs programmatically, but what you could try is having your "tab" be just an iframe host, with width/height basically set to 100%, and then dymically loading the content of the iframe

Comment: Can you provide any example of it ?

Comment: not really - basically your tab is just a web page with an iframe, set to width+height 100%, and the "src" set to wherever you want it to go

Comment: Web page renders as tab perfactly but it's static tabs of manifest file. Do you know any way to render it dynamically ?